# SQL Date Interval

Tags: ms-access

I have a table in ms access contains startDate and EndDate, how can i delete a row from the table using SQL when the difference between the two intervals reach 6 months?i don't need to give the date by me, i need it as i'm asking...
any help plz?

Comment: The most important question is - Why do you need to delete those records?  Is there a problem of some sort?  Millions of records?  An error message?

Comment: Explain in detail <> using one sentence.

Comment: please stop asking the same question over and over again - there are at least two exact duplicates out there.....

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateDiff](http://techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datediff.php):

```
DELETE FROM your_table
WHERE DateDiff("m", startDate, EndDate) = 6
```

For records 6 months and older:

```
DELETE FROM your_table
WHERE DateDiff("m", startDate, EndDate) <= 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You've been given a correct answer by @OMG Ponies:

```
  DELETE FROM your_table
  WHERE DateDiff("m", startDate, EndDate) <= 6
```

...but I would tend not to use this, as it won't use indexes. Instead, I'd use this:

```
  DELETE FROM your_table
  WHERE StartDate <= DateAdd("m", -6, EndDate)
```

Because you're testing a calculation against a field and not against a literal value, any index on StartDate can be used. For large tables, this could be a significant difference.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea in MSSQL is this:

```
DELETE FROM Archive WHERE [Date] < DATEADD(m, -6, GETDATE())
```

Not sure if Access has those functions but there should be something similar.

**EDIT**: 
As I suspected, Access does suport Transact-SQL and has these 2 date functions, but they are only available for a Microsoft Access project (.adp). Hope this helps.

Comment: DateAdd() is supported. For GetDate() you'd use Date(), but I don't think it answers the question, as he's looking not for records that are older than 6 months, but for records where the two date fields are 6 months apart.